# Definition of a real variable

Tags: variable-definitions

I would like to calculate a definite integral with a real parameter "a".
I tried Refine[Element[a, Reals]]  and Simbols [Element] Reals but the yield was a ConditionalExpression dealing Im[a] and Re[a]

Comment: Please show the whole expression you tried, including your integral. Have you tried adding an `Assumptions` option to your integral?

Comment: If you use an `Assuming` construct, the assumptions will be used by any enclosed function that uses the `Assumptions` option, e.g., for `Assuming[assump, Integrate[expr, {x, xmin, xmax}] // Simplify]` both the `Integrate` and the `Simplify` will make use of `assump`